# Recommendations for single user access Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am writing a desktop utility application to manage a small set of data. This application will be used by a singular person so I'd like to keep the database as simple as possible. I am considering XML or [SQL Server Compact 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) (SQL CE). I am leaning towards SQL CE because it will probably be easier/quicker to develop than XML. Are there any other worthwhile solutions worth considering? Is SQL CE the way to go?

Edit - Here are some more specifics on the data:

- Maybe a half a dozen tables
- No more than 5000 records
- Mostly CRUD operations
- Basic reporting/exporting to excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good experiences with Sql CE, that seems like a very reasonable solution given the scenario you're describing.  It has the added advantage of being much simpler to deploy than a separate solution as well, and I think that is a *very* big deal for a simple app like you describe.

I'm using it with Linq2Sql right now in my personal project, in fact.  :)

Answer (score 3):

SQLite would be my choice.

Comment: Why? What does SQLite offer over Sql Server Compact?

Comment: I agree on this highly.  SQLLite is the way to go.

Comment: SQLLite gives you the benefit of not requiring anything to be installed on the system where the software runs.   If you "must" use Microsoft, as a java developer I would create an app in java, use the standard odbc driver to connect to an Access database directly, and compile it as a standalone .exe .

Comment: What does SQL Server CE require that SQLLite does not?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx)

Comment: What does Sql Server Express offer over SQl Server Compact? Sql Server Compact is a single file, no background service which seems advantageous in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a number of parameters:

- How much data will you store
- Will you perform complex queries on the data
- What kind of performance demands to you have
- and more...

If you are going to store relatively small amounts of data, without complex relations, and without a great need to query the data in complex ways, XML might be enough. If you on the other hand expect a greater amount of data, need good query support and performance, SQL Server Express or some other lightweight database manager would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Firebird Embeeded.

[link text](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server CE is lightweight and simple, and if you're using Visual Studio you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a single user and a limited set of data, I'd recommend looking into db4o.  http://db4o.com

It's an object database that would allow you to store objects directly without having to translate them into tables.